# HierarchicalDataTemplate and HeaderedItemsControl with ControlTemplate fails to show nested data

Tags: wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate, xmldataprovider

I can get this pattern to work with `Menu` and `TreeView` but I must be missing something when I make an attempt with `HeaderedItemsControl`:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
<Page.Resources>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=foo}">
        <AccessText Text="{Binding XPath=@a}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="RootXml" XPath="/root/foo">
        <x:XData>
            <root xmlns="">
                <foo a="one">
                    <foo a="two" b="wow, two" />
                    <foo a="three" b="wow, three" />
                    <foo a="four" b="wow, four" />
                </foo>
                <foo a="one again">
                    <foo a="two others" b="wow, two others" />
                    <foo a="three the hard way" b="wow, three again" />
                </foo>
            </root>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <HeaderedItemsControl
        Header="My Foo List"
        ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RootXml}}">
    </HeaderedItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

In XamlPadX, this shows:

```
My foo list
    one
    one again
```

Do I need to do something with the `ControlTemplate` to get the data to display correctly? Or do I need a more elaborate (or an additional) `HierarchicalDataTemplate`? Also: how do we show the `foo/@b` data?

Comment: Found an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f66d0cab-d9a3-49b9-8cc0-ea4d80d7f9c1

Answer (score 3):

Here is a late answer.  Been trying to figure this out as well, but was not satisfied with the reasoning in the above answer and/or the linked answer, as the XAML pattern should be the same between all controls.

After a bit of time with jetbrains dotPeek, and combing thought the TreeView Control the answer is finally quite simple.  The TreeView and TreeViewItem override **IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride**  and **GetContainerForItemOverride** to the control which will hold the children (TreeViewItem in the TreeView Case). You can create two simple custom controls to handle this.

Your **HeaderedItemControl** class would be something like this:

```
public class MyHierarchicalViewItem : HeaderedItemsControl
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is MyHierarchicalViewItem;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return (DependencyObject)new MyHierarchicalViewItem();
    }
}
```

Your ItemControl (Equivalent to the TreeView or Menu) would be this:

```
public class MyHierarchicalView:ItemsControl 
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is MyHierarchicalViewItem;
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {

        return (DependencyObject) new MyHierarchicalViewItem();
    }
}
```

Your XAML would be largely the same, just putting referencing the correct control and adding the appropriate namespace (my case xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:").

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=foo}">
            <AccessText Text="{Binding XPath=@a}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type myControls:MyHierarchicalViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type myControls:MyHierarchicalViewItem}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="RootXml" XPath="/root/foo">
            <x:XData>
                <root xmlns="">
                    <foo a="one">
                        <foo a="two" b="wow, two" />
                        <foo a="three" b="wow, three" />
                        <foo a="four" b="wow, four" />
                    </foo>
                    <foo a="one again">
                        <foo a="two others" b="wow, two others" />
                        <foo a="three the hard way" b="wow, three again" />
                    </foo>
                </root>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>

        </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <myControls:MyHierarchicalViewItem
        Header="My Foo List"
        ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RootXml}}">
        </myControls:MyHierarchicalViewItem>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the deal:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
<Page.Resources>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="RootXml" XPath="/root/foo">
        <x:XData>
            <root xmlns="">
                <foo a="one" b="test1">
                    <foo a="two" b="wow, two" />
                    <foo a="three" b="wow, three" />
                    <foo a="four" b="wow, four" />
                </foo>
                <foo a="one again" b="test2">
                    <foo a="two others" b="wow, two others" />
                    <foo a="three the hard way" b="wow, three again" />
                </foo>
            </root>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type HeaderedItemsControl}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NestedFooItemTemplate">
        <AccessText Text="{Binding XPath=@b}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FooItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <AccessText Text="{Binding XPath=@a}" />
            <HeaderedItemsControl
                Header="My Nest"
                ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource NestedFooItemTemplate}}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./foo}"
                Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <HeaderedItemsControl
        Header="My Foo List"
        ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource FooItemTemplate}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RootXml}}">
    </HeaderedItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

`HierarchicalDataTemplate` is for tree views which have automatic child element expansion. In your case you can simply use a normal `DataTemplate`.